# Excel Graph Automatic Resizing of Axis Origin

Tags: excel, vba, graph, resize, autoresize

I have the following code which plots a scatter plot. Is there an elegant way to resize the plot area such that the x and y axis do not always automatically start from zero, but rather just below the lowest value? At the moment all my data points end up bunched up in one corner. Many thanks!

```
Set cht = ActiveChart
'GRAPH 1
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("AC13").Offset(jump * 50, 0), Range("AG23").Offset(jump * 50, 0))

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rng1.Left, Width:=rng1.Width, Top:=rng1.Top, Height:=rng1.Height)
 '(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .Chart.HasLegend = False
    .Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 18
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = 18
    '.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("U13:O40,T13:N40")
    Set srs = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            srs.XValues = Range(Range("U13").Offset(jump * 50, 0), Range("U13").Offset(jump * 50, 0).End(xlDown))
    srs.Values = Range(Range("T13").Offset(jump * 50, 0), Range("T13").Offset(jump * 50, 0).End(xlDown))

End With
```

Comment: can you try using .Chart.SetSourceData?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841196.aspx

Comment: .SetSourceData will not affect the axis autoscaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your y-range data was in cells `B1:B10` of the `ActiveSheet` then you could use code like this to start the range at 90% of the lowest value (ie just below)

```
Set cht = ActiveChart
cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0.9 * Application.Min([b1:b10])
```

Comment: If I want this value to be an Integer? Using .Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Int(0.8 * Application.Min(Range(Range("AL13"), Range("AL13").End(xlDown)))) does not work (I have tried other variations too)

Comment: Do you have the chart selected?I did use your `ActiveChart` syntax - the code ran for me

Comment: The scaling works for me perfectly. However I try to get it to scale to an integer using Int(). For example using `Set cht = ActiveChart .cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Int(0.8 * Application.Min(Range(Range("AK13"), Range("AN13").End(xlDown))))' gives me an error which I am unable to get around. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No dot before `cht` and reference ranges to active sheet: `cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Int(0.8 * Application.Min(ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("AK13"), ActiveSheet.Range("AN13").End(xlDown))))`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial:
[Calculate Nice Axis Scales in Excel VBA](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/calculate-nice-axis-scales-in-excel-vba/)