# Change Height of PivotChart to match height of PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I work heavily with PivotCharts, but have absolutely zero VBA experience. I have excel templates that are uploaded to a database, then can be downloaded as a report with the data from that database. I have a pivotTable/PivotChart combo on one sheet. Sometimes the table has 5 rows of data, and sometimes is has 1200 rows of data, depending on the database, timeframe, etc.

What I'd like to do, is have the chart take up the same number of rows as the table  + 3 in height, and always display in D3:J3 for width and starting position. This aligns the data with the charts.

I have found a similar ? from last year here: [Resize pivot chart when selecting different less/more values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180486/resize-pivot-chart-when-selecting-different-less-more-values)

It has not gotten me any results (or I'm doing something wrong).

Relevant info: table/chart is on Sheet4 ("Summary"), and under PivotTable Options, it is called "IdleSummary".

I appreciate any help that can be given, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, is to use a range object to size your chart like so:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Dim vPiv As PivotTable
    Dim vRowCount As Long
    Dim graphSizer As Range
    Dim theChart As ChartObject

    Set vPiv = ws.PivotTables("IdleSummary")
    vRowCount = ws.Range(vPiv.TableRange2.Address).Rows.Count + 3
    Set graphSizer = ws.Range("D3:J" & vRowCount)

    Set theChart = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=graphSizer.Left, Top:=graphSizer.Top, Width:=graphSizer.Width, Height:=graphSizer.Height)
    With theChart.Chart
        .SetSourceData vPiv.TableRange2
        .ChartType = xlArea 'replace with desired chartType
    End With

End Sub
```

EDIT, to answer comments:
Modifying the above code, and using the worksheet PivotTableUpdate event you could do like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    If Target.Name = "IdleSummary" Then
        Call Resize
    End If

End Sub

Sub Resize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Dim vPiv As PivotTable
    Dim vRowCount As Long
    Dim graphSizer As Range
    Dim theChart As ChartObject
    Dim charObj As ChartObject

    Set vPiv = ws.PivotTables("IdleSummary")
    vRowCount = ws.Range(vPiv.TableRange2.Address).Rows.Count + 3
    Set graphSizer = ws.Range("D3:J" & vRowCount)

    Set theChart = ws.ChartObjects(1)
    With theChart.Chart.Parent
        .Left = graphSizer.Left
        .Top = graphSizer.Top
        .Width = graphSizer.Width
        .Height = graphSizer.Height
    End With

End Sub
```

This is assuming you have just one chart, else you can replace the index (1) with the chart name, e.g. ("Chart 1"). If you interested in reading about events you can find an introduction here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response! That did create a chart for me in the proper dimensions. However, I simply want to change the height of a chart that already exists. I have to have specific formatting for my bar chart, and so I can't just create a new one. Is this even simpler?

Comment: Sorry, don't think I mentioned: I also need it to automatically resize. I know I tried just using worksheet_open and worksheet_change, neither of which  have given me any luck.

Comment: Added an edit with a modification to the code that updates an existing chart, when the pivot is updated